# std::thread causing application to abort with error R6010

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I have a class named Task which internally holds a member std::thread. The general idea is to create a thread that stays alive as requests of processing come.

```
class Task
{
public:
    Task();
    ~Task();

    void start();
    // some funny stuff here
protected:
    Task(const Task& ref);
    void main_function();

    std::thread m_thread;
    // more funny stuff like queues, mutexes, etc
}
```

In the function start() I do:

```
void Task::start()
{
    m_thread = std::thread(std::bind(&Task::main_function, this));
}
```

The problem is that this line calls abort() with the runtime error R6010. I've read somewhere that this may be caused by the destructor of m_thread being called without a previous join but, as the thread hasn't started yet, I can't join it.

I'm running this with Visual Studio 2012

**UPDATE:**

So I tried a test example and could not replicate the error. Then I replaced my start function in the problematic function as sugested to this:

```
void Task::start()
{
    assert(!m_thread.joinable());
    m_thread = std::thread(&Task::main_function,this);
}
```

But I still get the error R6010.
The call stack is:

```
msvcr110d.dll!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum) Line 226    C
msvcr110d.dll!abort() Line 62   C
msvcr110d.dll!terminate() Line 97   C++
msvcp110d.dll!_Call_func(void * _Data) Line 63  C++

msvcr110d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 354 C
msvcr110d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd) Line 337   C
```

**UPDATE2:**
Finally could replicate the problem. The code is as follows. Call foo() in the main function.

```
class Task 
{
public:
    Task() : m_exitFlag(false) 
    { 
        std::cout << "constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Task()
    {
        m_lock.lock();
        m_exitFlag = true;
        m_condlock.notify_all();
        m_lock.unlock();

        if (m_thread.joinable()) m_thread.join();
        std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl;
     }

     void start()
     {
         std::cout << "Task start" << std::endl;
         assert(!m_thread.joinable());
         m_thread = std::thread(&Task::main_function, this);
     }
protected:
     void main_function()
     {
         std::cout << "thread started" << std::endl;
         while(1)
         {
             m_lock.lock();
             while(m_queue.empty() && !m_exitFlag)
                 m_condlock.wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_lock));

             if (m_exitFlag)
             {
                 m_lock.unlock();
                 std::cout << "thread exiting" << std::endl;
                 return;
             }

             std::function<void()> f;
             if (!m_queue.empty()) f = m_queue.front();

             m_lock.unlock;
             if (f != nullptr) f();
         }
     }
     Task(const Task&ref) { }

     Task& operator=(const Task& ref) {
         return *this;
     }
};
void foo() {
    Task tk;
    tk.start();
}
```

I guess there's a race condition somewhere here, as it crashes some times and others don't.
One thread is inside the critical region in ~Task() and the other as the stack in Update1.

Comment: Can you give us a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the behavior? Most likely, the bug is exactly what you read, but it's hard to tell from just this code. (If your code calls `join` before it terminates, say in `~Task`, does it still get an error?)

Comment: Are you *certain* that `start` isn't somehow being called twice? Try guarding it with `assert(!m_thread.joinable())`. The full text of the error would be nice. Unrelated: The `std::bind` is unnecessary, `m_thread = std::thread(&Task::main_function, this);` will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: You have overloaded copy constructor, but not assignment operator! Please, never ever do this.

Comment: Are you compiling with the multi-threaded runtime?

Comment: Your testcase is not valid C++. Please post a proper testcase.

Comment: It misses some includes and a main, but the user ComicSansMS already found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never directly lock a mutex. C++ offers `lock_guard`, `unique_lock` et al. for a reason.

In particular, this section is problematic:

```
m_lock.lock();
while(m_queue.empty() && !m_exitFlag)
    m_condlock.wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_lock));
```

The newly constructed `unique_lock` will attempt to lock the already locked mutex `m_lock`. This [will cause undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock) if the mutex is a `std::mutex` or a possible deadlock if the mutex is a `std::recursive_mutex`.
Also note that this line is relying on a non-standard compiler extension as you bind the unnamed `unique_lock` [to a non-`const` reference when calling `wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

So first thing you have to do is make the lock a named variable. Then either pass a `std::adopt_lock` to the lock's constructor or better yet never lock the mutex directly but always wrap it in an appropriate lock management class.

For example,

```
m_lock.lock();
m_exitFlag = true;
m_condlock.notify_all();
m_lock.unlock();
```

becomes

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
    m_exitFlag = true;
    m_condlock.notify_all();
} // mutex is unlocked automatically as the lock_guard goes out of scope
```

This has the additional benefit that you won't leak locks if an exception is thrown inside the critical section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you take a function from the front() of the queue and then run the function after unlocking without first removing it from the queue with a pop(). Is this your intention? In such a case the next random thread may also acquire the same function and run it concurrently. Are those functions thread-safe? Also, you check for queue.empty() but where is the queue being emptied of functions after they are executed?